# Problems with writing JSON objects into a file

Tags: android, json, file

I'm writing a small application that get your location every 10 seconds and puts Latitude and Longitude into a JSON object. Than it should write Lat and Lon into a file in External Storage. I made run the application and I can see the file.json but there's only a string Lon into. Instead it should write a couple of values Lon Lat every time the location changes. What is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;
    TextView txtLat;
    String lat;
    String provider;
    protected String latitude,longitude;
    protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    FileOutputStream  outputStream;
    String latlon;
    String filename;
    File sdCardFile;
    FileWriter fw;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    filename="salvataggi.json";
    sdCardFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("Lat", location.getLatitude());
        jsonObject.put("Lon", location.getLongitude());
        latlon=jsonObject.toString();

          writeToFile(latlon, sdCardFile, fw);


       }catch (JSONException je) { }

}
public static void writeToFile(String latlon, File sdCardFile, FileWriter fw) {

    try{
        fw = new FileWriter(sdCardFile, true);
        fw.write(latlon);
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file should contain at least one lat-lon pair. Does it not? Your question makes it sound like it only contains a longitude

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of the details of the LocationManager object, but if your device hasn't moved at all (or less than a few meters), I don't think `onLocationChanged` should be triggered

Comment: Exactly, there is only a longitude value and nothing else... Even if the device doesn't move I can see the location changing a little sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

When you request location updates at a certain interval, you have no guarantee that you will receive updates at exactly that interval.  According to the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), all you can be certain of is that the updates will occur no faster than the given time duration.  If the GPS isn't getting updated locations, the listener may never be called at all.  It can take some time to get a GPS lock in the first place.

If you really need to provide some coordinate every 10 seconds, consider using a Handler to schedule a Runnable every 10 seconds that polls the value of [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) and makes sure the return value is not null. That returned Location may not be accurate, but it's at least something.

Comment: So, what should I do? Where should I call the Handler that calls a Runnable? Sorry, but I'm not really good in Android yet. I'm doing practice.